# $W(\Bbb{F}_p(t))$ is not valuation ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $W(\Bbb{F}_p(t))$ be ring of Witt vectors of $\Bbb{F}_p(t)$.

I want to prove $W(\Bbb{F}_p(t))$ is not valuation ring.

Take appropriate $x,y$ from fraction field of $W(\Bbb{F}_p(t))$ and calculate
$xy^{-1}$ and $yx^{-1}$.
I want to prove the titled statement by showing that these two elements are not in  $W(\Bbb{F}_p(t))$.

For example, take $x＝(0,1,0,・・・), y＝(0,t,0,・・・)$ and I want to calculate $xy^{-1}$.
But I'm having trouble calculating $y^{-1}$, could you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $K$ is a field of characteristic $p$, then in the ring of Witt vectors $W(K)$ we have
$$
p\cdot(x_0,x_1,\ldots)=(0,x_0^p,x_1^p,\ldots).
$$
In other words $x=p\cdot1$ and hence in the extension ring $W(K(t^{1/p}))$ we have
$$
x(t^{1/p},0,0,\ldots)=(0,t,0,\ldots)=y.
$$
This means that we can think of $(t^{1/p},0,0,\ldots)$ as $x^{-1}y$. It is in the integral closure of $W(K)$ but not in $W(K)$ itself. Therefore $W(K)$ cannot be a valuation ring.

Comment: On the other hand, if $K$ is a finite field (which is perfect), then $W(K)$ is a valuation ring. My guess is that the point of the exercise is to illustrate this?

Comment: Could you tell me why $x＝p・1$ ?

Comment: I think $x＝p・１$ only when $p＝2$.

Comment: @Iwasawa I need to recheck. I have only ever used characteristic two Witt vectors....

Comment: @Iwasawa My source is Jacobson's *Basic Algebra II*, section 8.10. In Lemma 2 (page 502 in my edition from 1980) he gives the result that multiplying by the integer $p$ amounts to shifting the components one position to the right and then applying the Frobenius to all of them. Does that not imply what I used?

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was my misunderstanding. And I think you should also say $xy^{-1}$ is not in $W(K)$ .

Comment: $x^{-1}y∈W(K)$ is not enough to conclude $W(K)$ is not valuation ring.

Comment: @Iwasawa A valuation ring is integrally closed. The calculation shows that $x^{-1}y$ is integral over $W(K)$ but not in $W(K)$ itself. Hence $W(K)$ cannot be a valuation ring.

Comment: Sorry, I made mistake, You are completely correct, thank you.

Comment: Is it difficult to take find $x$ in fraction field which does not belong to $W(K)$ and $x^{-1}$ does not also belong to $W(K)$?

Comment: You say $x^-{-1}y$ is integral over $W(K)$, but what is the monic polynomial over $W(K)$ which has $x^{-1}y$ as a root ? $T^p-1$ ?

Comment: @Iwasawa I think the calculations show that neither $x^{-1}y$ nor $xy^{-1}$ is in $W(K)$, just as you suspected in the beginning! The element 
$$x^{-1}y=(t^{1/p},0,0,\ldots)$$ is a zero of the monic polynomial
$$f(T)=T^p-(t,0,0,\ldots)$$ that has coefficients in the ring $W(K)$.

Comment: Using the extension ring $W(K(t^{1/p})$ may look like cheating, but I think it can be justfied. It looks like $W(K(t^{1/p}))$ has an unexpectedly large intersection with the field of fractions of $W(K)$.

Comment: Without using integrally closed argument, $x^{-1}y＝(t^{-1/p},0,0,・・・)$ is not in $W(K)$, so $W(K)$ is not valuation ring. Is this correct ?